# On restarting the Node.Js app throws EADDRINUSE error

Tags: node.js, rest

I know my question is repeated. Please read the question completely before marking as duplicate or anything.

I am learning node.js to create rest api & doing great on it.Everything was going smooth till i found this error( EADDRINUSE) on restart the app. This issue eat my precious hours but still not able to find the correct fix.

If the application is running for the 1st time, it launch's smoothly with out any port change for some reason we stop or restart the app this error message while be thrown from the server. Many of them suggested just change the port everything work smooth and I do agree with them.But When server is live & used worldwide you can't change the port to restart.

Adding Snippet of my Code.

app.js

```
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var config = require('./Config/config.js');
var  api = require('./apis/api');

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

app.all('/api/write/'+config.WRITE_API_VERSION+'/:apiName', function (req, res) {

    api.handle.apply(null, ['write', req.method.toLowerCase(), req.params.apiName, req, res]);
    console.log("in api end1"+req.body);

});

app.all('/api/read/'+config.READ_API_VERSION+'/:apiName', function (req, res) {


    api.handle.apply(null, ['read', req.method.toLowerCase(), req.params.apiName, req, res]);
    console.log("in api end2");

});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.contentType('application/json');
  next();
});


// more routes for our API will happen here

// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(config.PORT);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + config.PORT);
```

config.js

```
var configs = {
    ENVIRONMENT: "development",
    READ_API_VERSION: "v1.0",
    WRITE_API_VERSION: "v1.0",

    PORT: 8080
}

Object.freeze(configs);
module.exports = configs;
```

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "node app.js"
  }
```

Error Message

```
node app.js 
Magic happens on port 8080
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/home/ubuntu/vcare_backend/VCare/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/vcare_backend/VCare/app.js:47:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

After running the command sudo netstat -plnt

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3277/node       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1073/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1073/sshd
```

Comment: What's happening on line 47 of app.js?

Comment: How are you starting the application?

Comment: @AdrianLynch by running the node app.js command @ line 47 is listening the port 8080

Comment: what else is running on port 8080?

Comment: Whats the output of sudo netstat -plnt

Comment: @ojf any alternative command to check netstat in Mac

Comment: Depending on your version of Mac OS X, use one of these:

lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
lsof -n -iTCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
lsof -n -i:$PORT | grep LISTEN

Comment: @ojf Thanks for your quick response. I have update the post after running netstat -plnt

Comment: So that is telling you that node is already running on 8080. Try "% killall node" from the command line and then run your node app again

Comment: @ojf Yes, Good Move. This works.  Why does the node kill itself when I press command Z to terminate or stop the app running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104529/discussion-between-anand-and-ojf).

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question. The node process is hosted by the terminal window because you started it from there. Close the terminal and the child node process will die as well. This is expected and unavoidable. Im going to write an answer based on these comments so SO doesnt complain about loads of comments.

Comment: So you start the app. You try and start it again and it errors? Are you saying something else is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that node is already running on port 8080. This is shown by the first line returned by the netstat/lsof command. Killing the process will allow you to restart the node process. You can do this on a mac by using the command

```
killall node
```

Where node is the name of the process.

Answer (score 1):

Node is already running on your machine.

**In Terminal, find the running Node process with**
`ps -ax | grep node`

This will return a list of the running node processes.  The first column in the resulting list of processes is the process id (pid).

**Kill the running node process with**
`kill -9 <pid>`

This will kill the node process and free up the port for you to run your server.